# Plural des Singularetantums »Bewusstsein«

Tags: single-word-request, grammatical-number

Laut Wiktionary gehört das Wort „Bewusstsein“ zu jenen Wörtern, für die es keine Mehrzahl gibt; es ist also ein Singularetantum und steht damit in einer Reihe mit „Milch“, „Gesundheit“, „Post“ und vielen anderen Wörtern.

Nun schreibe ich aber gerade eine Geschichte, in der es unter anderem darum geht, dass das Bewusstsein der Person A mit dem Bewusstsein der Person B und dem Bewusstsein der Person C (usw., es sind sehr viele Personen) zu einer Einheit verschmilzt. Es verschmelzen also die […] mehrerer Personen zu einer Einheit.

Welches Wort passt am besten in die Lücke?

Zu vielen Einzahl-Wörtern gibt es Ausnahmen, wo in besonderen Situationen doch die Mehrzahl gebildet wird: Wenn es notwendig erscheint, spricht man schon mal von Sanden, Geldern und Stäuben. Aber mir fällt es schwer, eine plausibel klingende Mehrzahl zu „Bewusstsein“ zu bilden.

Kann mir jemand helfen?

### Nachtrag

Das englische Wort „mind“ trifft ziemlich genau das, was ich beschreiben will. Was ist die beste Übersetzung dafür? Weder „Bewusstsein“ noch „Geist“ noch „Seele“ decken meiner Meinung nach genau das ab, was „mind“ ist:

**Seele**
Ist per Definition auch nach dem Tod bis ans Ende der Zeit eine unteilbare und mit anderen Seelen nicht vermischbare Instanz.

**Geist**
Ich suche ja die Mehrzahl, und die wäre in diesem Fall „Geister“. Dabei denken aber viele sofort an durchsichtige Gestalten, die in weiße Leintücher gehüllt sind und auf Friedhöfen und in alten Schlössern wohnen.

**Bewusstsein**
Ist nach der Meinung von What (siehe seine Antwort) ein Zustand und keine Instanz. Darüber kann man je nach Kontext geteilter Meinung sein (siehe meinen zweiten Kommentar auf seine Antwort), aber ganz unrecht hat er nicht.

Comment: Man könnte die Definition von *Bewusstsein* auseinanderfrickeln und dann irgendwas mit *Wahrnehmungen* schreiben. Interessant wäre, um was es genau in dem Kontext geht, wenn du von *Bewusstsein* redest.

Comment: @Em1: Genauer möchte ich den Kontext nicht erläutern, weil ich die Geschichte vielleicht veröffentlichen will. Aber ich denke auch, dass ich "Bewusstsein" wohl durch einen anderen Begriff ersetzen muss. Auf Englisch wäre es einfach: "consciousnesses" (Siehe auch http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_Consciousnesses) - So hat halt jede Sprache ihre ganz speziellen Tücken.

Comment: Und wie ist's mit *Bewusstheiten*?

Comment: Ja, vielleicht. Ich muss da mal drüber schlafen.

Comment: Ich habe noch ein wenig recherchiert. Der Plural von Post ist demnach _Posten_ (nach Duden und Canoo.net) und von Milch ist er _Milche[n]_ (nach Duden (fachsprachlich) und sogar Wiktionary). Gesundheit gibt es wirklich nicht im Plural.

Comment: Also bei Vulkaniern ist das dann eine Gedankenverschmelzung, weil das Bewusstsein zweier Personen zu einem wird. Und bei den Borg hat das Kollektiv nur ein Bewusstsein. Dagegen klingt "Bewusstseine" einfach nur sehr doof.

Comment: Ja, verdammt, wie soll man das nennen, wenn die Iche verschmelzen, die Selbste. :) Die deutsche Sprache ist manchmal ganz schön geistfeindlich. :(

Comment: @chaero: Bei den Vulkaniern ist das eine vorübergehende Sache, wo jeder der Teilnehmer auch während der Verschmelzung seine Individualität behält. Beides trifft auf meine Geschichte nicht zu. Auch der Vergleich mit dem Borg-Kollektiv hinkt, weil auch hier jedes Individuum zumindest körperlich ein Individuum bleibt, auch wenn es einem gemeinschaftlichen Kollektiv unterstellt ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich wollte auch nicht andeuten, dass das irgendwas mit deiner Geschichte zu tun hätte. Aber für diese Fälle wurde jedenfalls auch kein neues Wort erfunden, also wirst du vielleicht auch mit einer Wortgruppe auskommen. Oder du erfindest ein ganz neues Wort. Aber "Bewusstseine" oder "Bewusstheiten" wird das stilistische Niveau nicht anheben.

Comment: Generell hat die [Gesellschaft zur Stärkung schwacher Verben](http://verben.texttheater.net/Plurale) manchmal Vorschläge für die Plurale von Singulariatantum, allerdings nicht für *Bewusstsein.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drei Möglichkeiten fallen mir ein:

1. Da das Wiktionary nicht befugter in solchen Fragen ist als der Duden, könntest Du einfach diesen als Referenz verwenden. Der sagt nicht, wie tatsächlich viele Quellen im Web, dass es keinen Plural gäbe, sondern nennt *[Bewusstseine](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bewusstsein)*, weißt aber darauf hin, dass die Verwendung *selten* sei.
2. Du lässt das Volk entscheiden: [Google](http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&q=%22bewusstseine%22) findet 44.000 *Bewusstseine* (Achtung: mit Gänsefüßchen googeln, damit der exakte Ausdruck gefunden wird).
3. Du verwendest, wie in den Kommentaren vorgeschlagen, eine Umschreibung. Da fällt der Community bestimmt noch einiges ein. *Gewahrheiten*, *Bewusstseinsinstanzen*,... (wahrscheinlich zeigt sich am Ende, dass *Bewusstseine* im Vergleich gar nicht so schlecht dasteht).

Philosophisch (aber jetzt greife ich unangemessen in die Geschichte ein) stellt sich natürlich die Frage, was *Bewusstsein* überhaupt ist und wie man eines vom andern unterscheidet, wenn es denn überhaupt mehrere gibt - immerhin handelt es sich hierbei um ein rein subjektives Phänomen. Sind es wirklich *Bewusstseine*, die verschmelzen, oder die *jeweils bewusst erlebten Wahrnehmungsräume*? Sind es die individuellen *Wassers* in den *Aquarien*, die sich *vereinigen*, wenn man viele kleine in ein großes kippt, oder unterschieden sich nur die *Fische* voneinander, die jetzt *einen großen Schwarm* bilden? Aber wer kann sagen, was hier die richtige Metapher ist...

Wenn Personae keine Option ist, wäre mein Favorit unterm Strich *Bewusstseine*.

Comment: Meine Favoriten sind in der Tat "Bewusstseinsinstanzen" und "Bewusstseine" wobei ich eher zu letzterem tendiere. Und da ich ich ohnehin einen Faible für seltene Wörter habe, und der Duden diese Variante auch gutheißt, werden es in meiner Geschichte wohl "Bewusstseine" werden. Der Vergleich mit Wasser passt übrigens sehr gut, den verwende ich nämlich auch in meiner Geschichte. Mehr will ich aber nicht verraten.

Comment: Es heißt "die Wasser" und nicht Wassers

Comment: Ich empfehle immer, zur Überprüfung von Wörtern die Google **Buchsuche** zu verwenden, statt der allgemeinen Googlesuche. Bücher sind, vor allem wenn sie älter sind, durch eine redaktionelle Prüfung gegangen und bilden eher die korrekte Standardsprache ab, während die allgemeine Googlesuche auch Blogs und Forenbeiträge findet, die von sprachlichen Schlampern verfasst wurden.

Answer (score 4):

Mir scheint, dass du bei deinem Verständnis des Begriffs Bewusstsein einem Irrtum unterliegst.

Für mich als Psychologen ist Bewusstsein keine Instanz, sondern ein Zustand (das Gegenteil von Bewusstlosigkeit), und dazu gibt es keinen Plural, genauso wenig wie zu Schlaf oder Hunger. Mein Hunger und dein Hunger bleiben weiterhin unser Hunger, denn der Hunger ist ja nicht ein Organ oder so etwas, sondern ein Zustand deines Organismus, der auch völlig verschwinden kann. Genauso kann dir auch der Zustand des Bewusstseins abhandenkommen, z. B. wenn du schläfst oder (falls du meinst, im Schlaf bist du bewusst im Traumland) wenn du ohnmächtig oder im Koma bist.

Wenn es um eine Instanz geht, die bewusstseinsfähig ist und also in den Zustand des Bewusstseins geraten kann, dann sind Ich, Selbst, Person usw. die üblichen Bezeichnungen. Und von diesen kann man sich vorstellen, dass sie verschmelzen, und die kann man auch in den Plural setzen.

---

Nachtrag:

Ich habe überlegt, ob ich meine bisherige Antwort ganz lösche, eine zweite einreiche oder diese editiere. Durch deine Anmerkungen, Hubert, bin ich nämlich auf eine ganz andere Idee gekommen. Schau mal, ob dir das taugt:

Anders als das Bewusstsein (ein Zustand) ist das Unbewusste (nicht: Unterbewusstsein!) in der Theorie Freuds eine Instanz, die zu eigenem, vom Ich unabhängigem "Denken" fähig ist. In der Theorie Jungs nun ist das Unbewusste (immer noch Singular) der einzelnen Menschen über das kollektive Unbewusste miteinander verbunden. Ich weiß nicht, wie Jung das formuliert (ich bin sicher, dass er keine "Unbewussten" bildet oder sowas), aber vielleicht kannst du dort mal nachschauen und sehen, wie er das beschreibt – und dann diese Art der Beschreibung übernehmen: den Plural im Singular ausdrücken durch die Beschreibung dessen, was passiert. In deiner Geschichte könnte das vielleicht so lauten:

"Das bisher getrennte, individuelle Bewusstsein der beiden vereinigte sich zu einem gemeinsamen, überindividuellen, kollektiven Bewusstsein, in dem beide gleichzeitig dieselben Gedanken und Einsichten hatten usw." oder du beschreibst einfach nur eine Person und sagst, dass das bei beiden passiert: "Das Bewusstsein beider Personen vereinigte sich in einem gemeinsamen Bewusstsein." oder "Sein Bewusstsein vereinigte sich mit dem Bewusstsein Peters."(keine Ahnung, was du genau vorhast, aber vielleicht gibt dir das eine Idee).

---

Noch ein Nachtrag (zu Olafs zweitem Punkt):

Bei der Googlesuche taucht ein Ergebnis auf, das mit "Hallo, ich habe 4 Bewusstseine" überschrieben ist. In der Psychologie gibt es das Modell der "multiplen Persönlichkeit". Wie wäre es mit "Persönlichkeit"? "Ihre Persönlichkeiten vereinigen sich zu einer einzigen, über zwei Körper verteilten Person."

Jedenfalls würde ich die fertige Geschichte dann gerne mal lesen :-)

Comment: Ich gebe dir recht. Die Engländer haben ein viel passenderes Wort: "mind". Leider gibt es keine exakte Übersetzung dieses Wortes ins Deutsche. "Seele" passt nicht, weil diese per Definition auch nach dem Tod eine individuelle Entität bleibt. "Geist" gefällt mir auch nicht, denn der Plural davon wäre "Geister", und damit assoziiere ich in weiße Leintücher gehüllte durchsichtige Gestalten die vorzugsweise auf Friedhöfen und in alten Schlössern wohnen.

Comment: Ich möchte meine soeben gegebene Zustimmung ein wenig differenzieren: Die Griechen kennen den Gott Hypnos, der den Menschen den Schlaf gibt (seinem Sohn Morpheus wird ähnliches Nachgesagt). Es wäre auch ein Gott des Hungers denkbar, der den Menschen Hunger einpflanzt. Schlaf und Hunger sind in diesem Kontext also durchaus Instanzen, die auf einen Menschen übertragen werden können, und genau in diesem Sinn verwende ich in meiner Geschichte das Wort "Bewusstsein".

Comment: Hab noch einen Nachtrag geschrieben, nachdem ich deine Kommentare gelesen habe.

Comment: Danke für deine Nachträge. Lies bitte auch meine Kommentare zu anderen Antworten hier auf dieser Seite (achte auf den Vergleich mit Wasser), dann wirst du verstehen, dass "Persönlichkeit" im Kontext meiner Geschichte nicht funktionieren kann. Tatsächlich hat das, was ich meine sehr viel mit Jungs Unbewussten zu tun. Ich werde dort mal nachlesen. Danke!

Answer (score 3):

Das klingt ziemlich nach Geschmackssache...

Mich persönlich bringt das Wort "Bewusstseine" zum Stolpern. "Bewusstseinsinstanzen" passt für mich nur in einem eher technisch/psychologischen Kontext, wenn Deine Geschichte also richtig in die technischen Details dieses Prozesses einsteigt.

Die beste Lösung für mich wäre, zu versuchen, das über Grammatik und Satzbau zu lösen:

> Das Bewusstsein der fünf Personen wird zu einer Einheit verschmolzen.
>
> Das Bewusstsein jedes Einzelnen wurde in das Gruppenbewusstsein aufgenommen.

Das klingt für mich rund und sagt auch das Richtige aus. Abgesehen von extrem spitzfindigen Lesern wird jeder sofort verstehen, was gemeint ist.

---

Möglicherweise wäre auch zu überlegen, ob Du nicht lieber einen ungewöhnlichen/seltenen/neuen Begriff für das Kollektivbewusstsein statt für das individuelle Bewusstsein der ursprünglichen Einzelpersonen wählen willst,  - aber vielleicht hast Du das ohnehin schon getan :)

Comment: Die Bewusstseine von Verstorbenen kehren in meiner Geschichte nirgendwohin zurück, sondern vermischen sich zu einem Kollektivbewusstsein, so wie sich viele Wassertropfen zu einem Ozean vermischen. Neugeborene erhalten aus diesem Gesamtbewusstsein ihr individuelles Bewusstsein, so wie wenn man einen Tropfen Wasser aus einem Ozean entnimmt. Das ist eine Variante einer Seelenwanderung, aber mir gefällt das Wort "Seele" nicht, weil die ja per Definition unvergänglich ist, während das Bewusstsein in meiner Variante ja ihre Individualität verliert.

Comment: "Das Bewusstsein der fünf Personen ..." ist grammatisch nicht korrekt. Vergleiche mit: "Das Haus der fünf Bauern" (Fünf Bauern wohnen in einem gemeinsamen Haus) vs. "Die Häuser der fünf Bauern" (Jeder Bauer hat sein eigenes Haus)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Richtig, dass es eigentlich nicht korrekt ist - gerade in der Literatur halte ich es aber für zulässig, in Problemfällen "Schönheit" vor "Richtigkeit" gehen zu lassen... :)
Und ein Gegenbeispiel: "Die fünf Raucher in meiner Firma setzen ihre Gesundheit aufs Spiel." 
Kann es sein, dass die Regel bei Singularetanta (?) nicht gilt?

Comment: Gutes Argument. Mir ist auch gerade aufgefallen, dass ich in meinem ersten Kommentar in dem Satz, der mit "Neugeborene" beginnt, diese Regel selbst gebrochen habe.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Oh, lol, das hatte ich gleich mal übersehen...

Answer (score -1):

Wie wäre es mit *Bewusstseinsform?*

Comment: Eine Bewusstseinsform eine bestimmte Form, also eine Variation, eines Bewusstseins. Der Plural, der eigentlich gefragt war, ist »Bewusstseinsformen«. Ich habe ein Bewusstsein. Ich habe aber keine Bewusstseinsform. In meiner Geschichte verschmelzen auch nicht die Bewusstseinsformen mehrerer Individuen zu einer vereinigten Bewusstseinsform, sondern es verschmelzen die Bewusstseine(?) zu einem vereinten Bewusstsein

Comment: Fortsetzung: Wenn du jemanden tötest, löscht du auch nicht seine Lebensform aus, sondern sein Leben.